# Cannot connect MongoDb Atlas inside Gatsby project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gatsby

I use Gatsby and MongoDb Atlas. I can connect my MongoDb from Compass or any other clients. However, I cannot connect from Gatsby. I get error always.

I try lots of thing to fix that. I remove all IP addreses from Network Access in MongoDb Atlas and try with no IP address, it doesnt work. Then, I try with only 0.0.0.0 Ip, nothing changed. Then I clear all npm packages and try but all is same.

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to 54.93.42.35:27017 closed
    at Timeout._onTimeout (E:\Kisisel\gatsbyTest\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\sdam\topology.js:438:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map {
      'cluster0-shard-00-00.tl25n.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-02.tl25n.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-01.tl25n.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
```

My connection string:

```
mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.tl25n.mongodb.net/<dbName>?retryWrites=true&ssl=true
```

Same connection string on Compass:
[image]

Network Access:
[image]

Comment: I see the following `localThresholdMS: 15,` and I also see this is a server selection timeout.  Most likely the Gatsby client is timing out too soon.  See if you can lengthen the timeout period.  Try like a minute or more to rule out timeout issues...

Comment: When I change `localThresholdMS` value, I get an error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined`

Comment: Maybe consider Gatsby is more difficult that it's worth?

Comment: Maybe but alternatives also diffucult. I try other generators, all of them missing some part.